# How can I find the next object in an array of objects that has a certain property set to false?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects (projects) as the following:

```
const projects= [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'project1',
    private: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'project2',
    private: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'project3',
    private: true
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'project4',
    private: true
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'project5',
    private: false
  }
]
```

if I set my current project id like this `currentProjectId = projects[0].id` how can I find the next object id in the array that has a private property set to false??

not too sure how to go about this I've tried to use `Array.prototype.fliter()` function to create a new array publicProjects with all objects that has private property set to false but unclear on how to grab the next object from the new array and assign it to a new variable called nextProjectId... to be honest I'm not quite sure if creating a new filtered array is the proper way of doing it either so any advise is much appreciated.

here is a link to [repl.it](https://repl.it/@neenus/findNextObjectId) I tried using `Array.prototype.find()` function on the new filtered publicPorjects array however find method always returning the first object in the array

basically this is what I'm trying to achieve...

if the currentProjectId is 1 nextProjectId is expected to be 2.. 
if currentProjectId is set to 2 then nextProjectId is expected to be 5 since the private property is set to true on 3 & 4... and finally if currentProjectId is set to 5 then nextProjectId is expected to be 1

Comment: @Neenus Is the array always going to be sorted based on `id`?

Comment: @nickzoum yes the array will always be sorted by id

Answer (score 4):

You could take a [`Generator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) and get only the items with `private: false`.

```js
const projects = [{ id: 1, name: 'project1', private: false }, { id: 2, name: 'project2', private: false }, { id: 3, name: 'project3', private: true }, { id: 4, name: 'project4', private: true }, { id: 5, name: 'project5', private: false }];

projects[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    var i = 0;
    if (this.every(({ private }) => private)) return; // prevent running forever
    while (true) {
        if (!this[i].private) yield this[i];
        i++;
        i %= this.length;
    }
}

var nextFalse = projects[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(nextFalse.next().value);
console.log(nextFalse.next().value);
console.log(nextFalse.next().value);
console.log(nextFalse.next().value);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Oohh thats a very nice answer!

Comment: Except that it does not work: "*if currentProjectId is set to 5 then nextProjectId is expected to be 1*".

Comment: @NinaScholz This is very interesting solution being somewhat new to javacript I've just heard of generator functions today so thank you for that :) however my question is how can I set the value of `i` to currentProjectId without breaking the code when the currentProjectId is 5??

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to `filter` the array, `findIndex` the element and return the next element:

```js
const projects = [
  { id: 1, name: "project1", private: false },
  { id: 2, name: "project2", private: false },
  { id: 3, name: "project3", private: true },
  { id: 4, name: "project4", private: true },
  { id: 5, name: "project5", private: false }
];

const getNextProject = (id, pr) => {
  const f = pr.filter(o => !o.private)
  return f[f.findIndex(o => id === o.id) + 1] || f[0]
}

console.log(getNextProject(1, projects)) // returns { id: 2 ... }
console.log(getNextProject(2, projects)) // returns { id: 5 ... }
console.log(getNextProject(5, projects)) // returns { id: 1 ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using `Array.slice` on the original array to search only after the current index.

An example:

```js
const projects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'project1',
    private: false,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'project2',
    private: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'project3',
    private: true,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'project4',
    private: true,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'project5',
    private: false,
  },
]

const findNextPrivateProject = (currentProjectId, projects) => {
  const currentProjectIndex = projects.findIndex(
    project => project.id === currentProjectId
  )
  return projects
    .slice(currentProjectIndex + 1)
    .find(project => !project.private)
}

let currentProjectId = 1
document.getElementById('next-private-project').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const nextPrivateProject = findNextPrivateProject(currentProjectId, projects)
  console.log(nextPrivateProject)
  
  currentProjectId = nextPrivateProject.id
  if (currentProjectId >= projects[projects.length - 1].id)
    currentProjectId = 1
})
```

```html
<button id="next-private-project">Find Next Private Project</button>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works? If the id 5 is entered then 1 is expected as the output

Comment: It's just because I reset the currentProjectId to 1 after being 5. the `findNextPrivateProject` works fine, it's just my reset added for the example which skips the first item.

Comment: Ah, I get you, the demo was just misleading :P

Answer (score 0):

Arguably the most idiomatic way is to use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) one or two times:

```js
const projects= [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'project1',
    private: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'project2',
    private: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'project3',
    private: true
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'project4',
    private: true
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'project5',
    private: false
  }
];

const condition = obj => !obj.private;

function getNextProject(projects, id) {
  return projects.find(obj => obj.id > id && condition(obj)) || projects.find(condition); 
}

console.log(getNextProject(projects, 1));
console.log(getNextProject(projects, 2));
console.log(getNextProject(projects, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

There could many arrangements but i choose to just make changes in your method setNextProjectId:

```
function setNextProjectId() {
  // find index of current Project Id
  var currentProject = publicProjects.find(x => x.id === currentProjectId );

  if(currentProject){
    var index = publicProjects.indexOf(currentProject, 0);
    nextProjectId =  publicProjects[index + 1].id;
    return;
  } else
  {
    nextProjectId = publicProjects[0];
  }

}
```

or

```
function setNextProjectId() {
  // find index of current Project Id
  var index = publicProjects.findIndex(x => x.id === currentProjectId );

nextProjectId = index >= 0 ? publicProjects[index + 1].id : publicProjects[0].id;
}
```

here you can check it out: https://repl.it/@IrshadAli/ShyGrayMachinecode

Answer (score 0):

In case project ids are not sorted the code must still be able to find next occurrence

```js
const projects= [
        {
          id: 51,
          name: 'project1',
          private: false
        },
        {
          id: 82,
          name: 'project2',
          private: false
        },
        {
          id: 93,
          name: 'project3',
          private: true
        },
        {
          id: 24,
          name: 'project4',
          private: true
        },
        {
          id: 65,
          name: 'project5',
          private: false
        }
      ]

      var result;
      const getNextProject = (id) => {
        var currentIndex =  projects.findIndex(el => {
          return (el.id == id && !el.private);
        });
        
        currentIndex += 1;

        if(currentIndex) {
          for(var i = currentIndex; i < projects.length; i++) {
            if(!projects[i].private){
              result = projects[i];
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        return result;
      }

      console.log(getNextProject(51));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Array#reduce` and keep the smallest id that is smaller than the current project id (for `currentProjectId = 2`, the value would be `1`) and the smallest id that is larger than the current project id (for `currentProjectId = 2`, the value would be `5`). If the second value exists get it, otherwise get the first value. This will work even when the list isn't order properly. And it only goes through the array once.

```js
// Just used JSON.parse to save space and there's no need to scroll down
const projects = JSON.parse(`[{"id":1,"name":"project1","private":false},{"id":2,"name":"project2","private":false},{"id":3,"name":"project3","private":true},{"id":4,"name":"project4","private":true},{"id":5,"name":"project5","private":false}]`);

function getNextId(currentProjectId) {
  var result = projects.reduce(function(minList, item) {
    if (item.private || currentProjectId === item.id) return minList;
    var index = currentProjectId < item.id ? 1 : 0;
    return minList[index] = Math.min(minList[index], item.id), minList;
  }, [Infinity, Infinity]);
  return result[1] === Infinity ? result[0] : result[1];
}

console.log(getNextId(0)); // 1
console.log(getNextId(1)); // 2
console.log(getNextId(2)); // 5
console.log(getNextId(3)); // 5
console.log(getNextId(4)); // 5
console.log(getNextId(5)); // 1
```

Comment: Thanks @nick for the speedy answer but that's not really giving me what I want to achieve

Comment: Why not? please run the snippet